# My fonts (UniversLT) are not displaying on IE11

Tags: css

enter code here1. The following css code is not working in IE11. It works fine in all other browsers.

```
 2. code block:

 @font-face {
               font-family: 'UniversLTStdLightCondensed';
               src: url('../fonts/universltstd-lightcn.eot');
               src: url('../fonts/universltstd-lightcn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('../fonts/universltstd-lightcn.woff') format('woff'),
               url('../fonts/universltstd-lightcn.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('../fonts/universltstd-lightcn.svg#UniversLTStdLightCondensed') format('svg');
         }
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your code?
It is un-readable right now.

Comment: is it looking fine now?

Comment: can you please help me with this....its just displaying default font in IE11..

Comment: i'm not realy sure but so many SRC: looks weird